# Adding new contents to use in gracenote

Tags: gracenote

I was looking for a second screen solution and I found gracenote video and sound recognition.
I wanted to ask if there are sdks to use your technology and also if new contents can be added by gracenote's customers to be used on the sdk, and if so how can it be done.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can register on the [Gracenote Developer Portal](https://developer.gracenote.com/) to access some of the SDK and documents.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have posted on forums and there were no answers, I messaged at facebook and they told me to email support. I emailed support and they told me to ask on stackoverflow. and now in stackoverflow you tell me to go back to forum! Thanks great

Comment: @m0j1My Bad. I actually meant the Developer Portal and not the Forum (fixed the answer) for downloading the SDK.

Comment: Also regarding adding new content by customers, you should be more specific about use cases as it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. But generally this is not a supported feature.